# How to upgrade properly from solr 4.0 to 4.2?

Tags: solr

My solr Update extract handler stopped working after upgrading from 4.0 to 4.2

When I upgraded from solr 4.0 to 4.2 suddenly all the file uploads using /update/extract stopped working. I noticed a class was missing.

I've solved this by making by changing solrconfig(from 4.2) with the changes I had in 4.0.

***Because of al these problems I'm wondering whats the best way to upgrade from Solr 4.0 to 4.2?*** (or any other version)

I just copied the new war,dist folder and contrib folder and tought it would be fine but it sure isn't. 
I know re-indexing is recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically when I upgrade between Solr versions, I follow the steps outlined below...

1. Read the entire release notes for the new release. Especially checking the "Upgrading from Solr X.x.x" section. Here are the [4.2.0 Release Notes](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_0/changes/Changes.html#4.2.0) Also pay attention to any other items in the Detailed Change List that may apply to your instance.
2. Download the latest release and compare the `solrconfig.xml` and `schema.xml` in the `/example/solr/collection1/conf` folder with the same files from the version of Solr from which I am attempting to upgrade (Solr 4.0 in your case). I use a tool like [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) or something similar to help highlight the differences.
3. Examine the differences found in step 2. Research the changes (using Release Notes, [Solr Issues Tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR), [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr), etc.) and determine what impact there will be (if any) with what I have actually implemented in my Solr instance.
4. Stand up a Solr instance running the new version with appropriate config changes for my implementation and then test accordingly.

Yes, I agree that re-indexing is best when you can, as the underlying version of Lucene is changing as well and a re-index will be required to leverage any new features or improvements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I had read the release notes and had to change a Queryparserplugin Exception.